# how can i test at runtime if i'm running on ios 5 or higher?

Tags: iphone, ios, runtime

I want to use the IOS 5 username/password AlertView style in case I'm running on ios5, and show my own popup when I'm running on IOS4 and lower.

How can I at runtime detect the OS version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generally don't want to check the OS version, but instead want to see if the specific selector you're looking for exists.

```
if ([fooAlertView respondsToSelector:@selector(alertViewStyle)])
    //Yay!
```

Comment: I thought there would be something like: if(iosVersion >= 5) letsgo. But testing the selector makes sense!

Comment: i have discovered that there are situations in which the above test does not always behave as i had expected.  i would perform a test on an instance of AVAudioPlayer for setEnableRate: , and it would *always* fail, even when run on iOS, and even when then actually calling setEnableRate: on the object just tested would actually succeed!

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *sysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

This should do the trick. Make sure to keep it as string.

Comment: After thinking about it more Joshua's response would be more suitable. since iOS 6 will most likely have the same capability and you'd have to edit your code.

Comment: strange that the version is a string, so you can not say if(sysver>5.0). Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Well you can use it as a double but it's easy to make mistake. Using the selector is really the best case, cause you are not sure if >5.0 will support your required selector.

Comment: Just quick clarification on why the version is a string. Think about 4.3.2, how would you deal with that as a double?